# Are there any specific requirements for exporting a phonegap application to windows phone 7.1 +?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone

I am developing an application using phonegap. I have successfully exported the application for android, ios, blackberry and symbian. But when the application is exported for windows phone(7 and 8) the index.html is displayed completely and not the needed sections only (UI not displayed correctly), in addition no click event is working.

---

Are there any structural requirements specific for windows phone platforms?
Also when debugging the application i keep getting "**Error calling js to fire nativeReady event. Did you include cordova-x.x.x.js in your html script tag?**" even though i included the cordova-2.6.0 in my index.html page and set all items as content in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there was a problem in the html. Windows phone does not accept the doctype as lower case. ﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿`<!doctype html>` has to be changed to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: in my project it's already <!DOCTYPE html> still getting same error. Any idea?